# The in_array method only ran once?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a function that checks if the entered words are already in my DB.

I'm using the following code:

```
public function contains($string, $pieces)
{
    $this->getWords();
    $arr = $this->_data; // Get everything from DB

    $words = array();
    $foundWords = array();
    foreach($arr as $key)
    {
        $words[] = $key->word; // Put words in array
    }

    foreach($words as $item)
    {
        if (in_array($item, $words))
        { // Check if entered words are in the DB array

            $foundWords[] = $item; // Put already existing words in array

            print_r($foundWords);

            echo "Match found: ";
            echo $item . '<br>'; // Echo found words

            return true;
        }
        echo "Not found!";
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is, it only checks the first word from the entered words array.
Does anyone know why this might be happening?

***Example:***

User enters `'This is a test'`.
The DB contains the following words: `This, is, a, test`

The output of the code should now be `Match found: This, is, a, test`, and the `$foundWords` array should contain these words.

Instead, it only finds the first word and the `$foundWords` array only contains the first word. So, `Match found: This`.

Comment: You do know what `return` does in a function/method, don't you?

Comment: you need to use a `break` statement here and at the last line of function return your value.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for notifying me about that. I totally forgot that it stops the function. That solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable for return status from the function. Here i use `$flag` variable for checking the status of the word. Default i set the variable as false, and if the word found then turn the variable as `true` and `break`from the loop and return the `flag`.

```
public function contains($string, $pieces){
    $flag = false;
    $this->getWords();
    $arr = $this->_data; // Get everything from DB

    $words = array();
    $foundWords = array();
    foreach($arr as $key) {
        $words[] = $key->word; // Put words in array
    }

    foreach($words as $item) {
        if (in_array($item, $words)) { // Check if entered words are in the DB array

            $foundWords[] = $item; // Put already existing words in array

            print_r($foundWords);

            echo "Match found: ";
            echo $item . '<br>'; // Echo found words

            $flag = true; //set true and break from the loop
            break;
        }else{
            echo "Not found!";
            $flag = false;
        }               
    }
    return $flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "returns" and check if you find any word after all:

```
 foreach($words as $item) {
        if (in_array($item, $words)) { // Check if entered words are in the DB array

            $foundWords[] = $item; // Put already existing words in array
        }
    }
  if(count($foundWords) == 0) {

        echo "Not found!";
  }
  else
  {  
            echo "Words: ";
            print_r($foundWords);
  }
```